# how to make a delete popover view like the one in the attached picture in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to make this view.
How should I do?

When I click the tag, and pop "delete" .

[image]

Comment: yap. Have any about tags example about that?

Comment: What you want is UIMenuController. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimenucontroller

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you to achieve what you want:

```
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
    UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" action:@selector(btnDelete:)];
    UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menuCont setTargetRect:CGRectMake(30, rect.origin.y+10, 130, 20) inView:yourView];
    menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowUp;
    menuCont.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:menuItem,nil];
    [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

Also you need to specify the delegates.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
BOOL retValue = NO;
if (action == @selector(paste:) )
    retValue = NO ;
else if ( action == @selector(cut:) || action == @selector(copy:) )
    retValue = NO;
else
    retValue = [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
return retValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Present the alert controller as pop over. Put only one button in alert controller, set background colour as black. Using this definitely you will get result. But I don't know is this is the correct solution for that?.